# Return response from React api post for processing in front end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch

How can I take this code and make it so that it returns the JSON response as a string (this is using typescript)? This function exists in a class made to handle api interactions. Right now I can see the response in the chrome network tools, but I'm not really sure how to capture that response to display on the front end. All I want to do is format the data into a table for easy viewing

```
public getInventory(newitem: string){
   return fetch(this.apgendpoint,{
       method: POST,
       headers: this.headers,
       body: newitem,})
.then((response) => {
console.log(response);
if (!response.ok) {
          this.handleResponseError(response);
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.handleError(error);
      });
  }
if (!response.ok){
this.handleResponseError(response)
```

One more thing. On the front end I call the function:

```
void inventoryAPI.getInventory(items)
```

With items being a list of inventory items to be queried

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify()` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Just tried that per your suggestion, returned JSON.stringify(response.json());

then in the front end code added this:

const apiResponse = inventoryAPI.getInventory(items)
console.log(apiResponse);

and now it prints Promise { <state>: "pending" }

Answer (score 0):

With `fetch`, the first return is a `response` object. If you need to read JSON, you need to return from the first response.

An example is

```
const json = fetch('https://api.github.com/users/hhimanshu')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

A running demo is https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-almeida-tqxc4?file=/src/App.js:58-187.

Look at the console tab to the bottom-right

Comment: Interesting, that does work to break out the data which is what I want, but when i call my function from the main front end code, it still prints out Promise { <state>: "pending" }

FYI I did make sure to return JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: Can you reproduce the code on codesandbox and paste the link here?

Comment: Actually I resolved the promise issue but I have another question. In my main code, I generate my query, then call the function to post the query. If I console.log the data returned from the post function, it now says empty string. I also have a console.log within the api helper class which is also supposed to print out the response data. In the front end code, it prints empty string, and then a few seconds later, the api class prints the results of the query.

My question: why is there a delay in the two, and why wouldn't my function wait for the data to be populated to return?

Comment: I think the issue is that I don't really understand how Promises work in Typescript. Right now the function is returning a pending promise. How I can I ensure that it waits for the data to be fetched before returning the string. I added in:

.then((data) => {
        return JSON.stringify(data);
      })

And it still returns a promise